# Hosting that supports POT-files?

Tags: hosting, translation

I've had a heck of a time trying to get some .po & .mo language files working with my Wordpress installation (Buddypress & bbPress). After a few days of failure I sent a support ticket to one.com (where I got my hosting) and they replied with this:

*Hello,*

*Thank you for contacting one.com!*

*I am sorry, but POT-files is not supported on our servers.*

*Best Regards*

Well, now I'm screwed. So, my question:

**Does anyone know a way to move my domain to a different hosting website that supports POT-files (.po & .mo)?**

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Did you try upload via FTP? After all even Wordpress uses .mo files itself.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing. Uploading my files through FileZilla, in the right directory, with the right filenames. And it won't work.. What I've done as a last & not favorable option is to go through all files individually and translate each...